# Having 1 drawable folder instead of 3 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey all, right now I have a drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi folder inside my res directory... I hear that android now filters out applications based on screen size and density. All of my images are inside the drawable-hdpi folder. Should I make just 1 folder called "drawable" and delete the other 3? Or should I convert all the images to the proper size and place them inside all three folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave the folders as they are and put your medium density images in drawable-mdpi and hign density images in drawable-hdpi folder. I would leave the small density screens and let android scale them. But if you are worried about small density then put those in the drawable-ldpi directory too.
[There are only a very few devices that support small screens.](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html)

Now for supporting multiple screens you need to make some changes in your manifest. Here is the [explanation of what developers need to do to support multiple screens.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

A note of caution if you are supporting 1.5 devices. In this case put all the images in your drawable-mdpi into drawable folder. That is because 1.5 devices do not support multiple screens and they recognize images in drawable folder.